# Clojure: Using a stream without holding head. Is this correct?

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I want to put a lazy sequence somewhere to provide data as needed. I know I have to avoid keeping hold of the head of the sequence. I came up with the follwoing solution, did I miss something?

```
(defn headless [s] 
  (let [a (atom s)] 
    (fn 
      ([]  (let [s @a r (first s)] 
             (swap! a rest) r)) 
      ([n] (let [s @a rs (take n s)] 
             (swap! a #(drop n %)) rs)))))
```

Usage example, this simple generator just gives the natural numbers.

```
(def nums (headless (iterate inc 0)))

(nums 5)
; (0 1 2 3 4)

(nums)
;5
```

Update: The "test" should use dorun, not doall. See solution by lgrapenthin

A (not overly realistic) test with

```
(doall (map #(nums %) (repeat 20)))
```

crashed after 5 min usage of all 4 cores with an Exception (OutOfMemoryError Java heap space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works.

This form:

```
(doall (map #(nums %) (repeat 20)))
```

will generate an infinite amount of (nums 20) and never return. You can use `dorun` instead, to drop the generated `(nums 20)` and not keep them in memory. However, it will not return because `(repeat 20)` generates an infinite lazy seq.

Slightly more readable version of `headless`

```
(defn headless [s] 
  (let [a (atom s)] 
    (fn 
      ([]  (let [s @a]
             (swap! a rest)
             (first s))
      ([n] (let [s @a]
             (swap! a (partial drop n))
             (take n s)))))))
```

Comment: Ah, so doall realizes the sequence, dorun just runs it. Thank you.